# Angular2 unit testing with karma and angular-cli do not work

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I just build an application with the official angular-cli on ubuntu 14.04 with nam version v2.14.12 and node version v4.2.6 and karma version v0.13.19,

I did steps below:

```
sudo ng new Project
cd Project
ng serve
```

The project is working, I have project Works! on localhost:4200

```
ng build
```

Built project successfully. Stored in "dist/"

```
cd dist
```

I am now in the building project folder

```
karma start
```

I just have a confirmation message that says:
    Karma v0.13.19 server started at http://localhost:9876/

What I did wrong? Why no unit testings appear?

Thanks :)

Comment: I have followed the github instructions https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Did you create a configuration file with `karma init`? Are you running `karma start` in the same directory as the configuration file? If so, please show us what the configuration file looks like.

Comment: @MattScarpino the karma config file is generated as part of the `ng new Project` command

Answer (score 1):

When you are running `karma start` you need to do so from the project root directory, not the dist directory.

The instructions in the README regarding `dist` is to ensure that the project has been compiled.